# Is there any way to get specific id from element and use it afterwards in Selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

For example, i've got elements with a specific id:

> my_id[1][50]
>
> my_id[1][51]
>
> ...

I need to find first element (with 50) and use this number in 'type' command afterwards. (i need to manipulate with selectors from test generator in php code).

To be more clear, i need to do something like this:

> $s->command('type', 'some_id[1][${elementId}+1]', '...');

I'm using **selenium 1.0.1**

Comment: selenium or selenium2?

Comment: im using first version

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this is to use xpath selector:

```
xpath=(//textarea[contains(@id, 'my_id')])[i]
```

Eventually i can manipulate with 'i' any way i want.